# PHP Download - File emty

Tags: php, file, file-io, download, readfile

I try to download files uploaded to my server, but after download, they are empty, name and ending are correct, but not the rest.
I try downloading it with that script:

```
<?php

session_start();

$file = basename($_GET['file']);
$path = 'uploads/'.$_SESSION['id']."/".$file;

if(!$path){ // file does not exist
    die('file not found');
} else {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($path);
    exit;
}
```

I also tried multiple types of header but it doesn't seem to work.. Files to downnload can be all types, txt-files, pictures, .exe-files, etc.

FYI: When uploading the files they are saved in folders named with the user-id, that's how the path comes about. And the path seems to be completely right.

The file I try to download (as test-file) is a .txt-file, when opening it in the browser (`....com/uploads/23/test.txt`) I get the content, so it's not empty.

Does anybody have an idea, what the problem could be?...

Comment: What $file value you are getting?

Comment: try to check with [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function whether file exist or not.

Comment: $file-value is exactly the name of the file, for example `test.txt`
No duplicate, I know this thread, but it doesn't change my problem.
You're right, `if(!file_exists($path){die()}`makes it dying... What could the problem be?